# How to run Findbugs and PMD on a specific jdk in hudson?

Tags: java, ant, hudson

I have hudson deployed on tomcat6 and jdk 1.5
in global manage hudson i configured java 1.4 and java 1.5
for my new job i have selected java 1.4
i didn't specify JAVA_HOME in environment variables

Answer (score 4):

Your build is running with Java 1.4.  However, [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) requires Java 1.5 or later.

PMD can run under Java 1.4, but the default classes expect 1.5.  According to the PMD release notes,

> "to run pmd with 1.4, use the files from the java14 directory (weaved pmd jar and support files)".

You could probably manage it as a two-step build job by customizing the java options for each step.  But if it were me, I would have the main build kick off the PMD and Findbugs actions in a separate downstream build.  That way you could still use 1.4 for your project build, but you could use 1.5 or 1.6 for the analysis (Findbugs needs 1.5 or 1.6 but it can analyze code compiled with 1.4).  This would be simple to manage using the Hudson JDK definitions.

Actually, no.  If it were me, I would use the latest JDK anyway and simply set the target version to 1.4.

Comment: thanks for your response Zac.
Though i removed findbugs target in build.xml i am getting this exception.
first i would like to build my project with java 1.4 in hudson for PMD. later i can run findbugs on 1.5 as downstream as u said.
Though i selected java1.4 for my job in hudson, i get the above exception. is anything i need to change in ant ?

Comment: What happens if you build with 1.5? Does it build successfully? Also, if you remove FindBugs, are you getting the *exact* same exception?

Comment: @Sravan based on the "at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:583)" portion of the stack dump I would guess that you have a findbugs <taskdef> still in your build.  You need to remove all traces of findbugs if you are going to stick with 1.4

Comment: @Sagar  I'm getting errors when i build code on 1.5 due to deprecated methods.And after removing FindBugs also i'm getting the same exception.  
The actual problem is, i specified java1.4 for my job in hudson configure. but, somewhere its taking java1.5 and getting UnsupportedClassVersionError

Comment: @Zac After removing all the traces of FindBugs also i'm getting the same exception.

Comment: @Sravan: can you post your error exception after you remove all FindBugs related code, and also the exception when you are using 1.5?

Comment: @Sagar: 
Following is the exception when i removed findbugs and specify 1.4 in hudson job configure.


[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin\ant.bat && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: build.xml

pmd:  

BUILD FAILED
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/sourceforge/pmd/ant/PMDTask (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)

Comment: @Sravan are you even reading the exception log?  It is clearly talking about the pmd task now.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used `-DtargetJDK=1.6` along with the other goals and the PMD Plugin worked for me just fine.